# How to disable text selection for mobile long press but preserve haptic feedback?

Tags: javascript, css, ios, mobile, haptic-feedback

I'm trying to do the opposite of what [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65964830/disable-long-press-vibration-in-javascript-for-ios) asks. I'm implementing a functionality on my webpage where long pressing an element on mobile triggers a function.

I used `long-press-event` [here](https://github.com/john-doherty/long-press-event). However, long pressing not only triggers the function but also selects some text on the screen. So I added the following CSS to disable text selection.

```
body {
    -webkit-user-select: none;
    -khtml-user-select: none;
    -moz-user-select: none;
    -ms-user-select: none;
    user-select: none;
    -webkit-tap-highlight-color: rgba(0,0,0,0);
}
```

This disabled text selection but also the haptic feedback that comes with it. Is there a way to prevent this, or should I use something like Capacitor to trigger an artificial vibration?

Testing on iOS Chrome.